# Como recorrer un excel y subir la data a una base de datos

Tags: python, mysql, excel, pandas

Bueno prácticamente lo que dice el titulo, necesito acceder a un Excel recorrerlo y cada fila subirla a una tabla de la base de datos, lo que llevo es lo siguiente pero no veo que sea la mejor forma de hacerlo

imagen del excel
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

````
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector


nombre_excel = 'directorio\excel.xlsx'
equipos_industriales = pd.read_excel(
                    nombre_excel, 
                    sheet_name='hoja',
                    header=10
                    )
df = pd.DataFrame(equipos_industriales)
df.columns = df.iloc[0]


cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
    user='usuario',
    password='contraseñ',
    database='base de datos',
    port=3309
)
cursor = cnx.cursor()

sql = (
    "INSERT INTO appcatastro_catastroequipomedico " 
    "(servicio_clinico, recinto, clase, subclase, nombre_equipo, marca, modelo, serie, numero_inventario, anio_adquisicion, vida_util, vida_util_residual, propio, estado, garantia, anio_vencimiento_garantia, bajo_plan_mantenimiento) " 
    "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    )

primera_iteracion = True

for ubi, cls, sbcl, nei, mrc, mdl, sri, nin, ada, vu, vur, pro, est, grt in zip(
    df['UBICACIÓN'].values, 
    df['CLASE'].values, 
    df['SUBCLASE'].values, 
    df['NOMBRE EQUIPO INDUSTRIAL'].values, 
    df['MARCA'].values,
    df['MODELO'].values,
    df['SERIE'].values,
    df['N° INVENTARIO'].values,
    df['AÑO DE ADQUISICIÓN'].values,
    df['VIDA ÚTIL'].values,
    df['VIDA ÚTIL RESIDUAL'].values,
    df['PROPIO / ARRIENDO / COMODATO'].values,
    df['ESTADO (BUENO / REGULAR / MALO / BAJA)'].values,
    df['EN GARANTÍA (SI / NO)'].values
    ):
    
    if primera_iteracion:
        primera_iteracion = False
        continue    
    if any(pd.isnull(value) for value in [ubi, cls, sbcl, nei, mrc, mdl, sri, nin, ada, vu, vur, pro, est, grt]):
        continue
    
    data = ('', '', cls, sbcl, nei, mrc, mdl, sri, nin, ada, int(vu), vur, pro, est, grt, 0, '')
    cursor.execute(sql, data)
    cnx.commit()
    # print(f'{ubi} - {cls} - {sbcl} - {nei} - {mrc} - {mdl} - {sri} - {nin} - {ada} - {vu} - {vur} - {pro} - {est} - {grt}')


cursor.close()
cnx.close()```
````

Comment: hasta al momento funciona pero busco una mejor forma de hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

Descargo de responsabilidad: las pruebas fueron hechas usando sqlite, pero me enfoqué en que funcione en pymysql.

##### Consejos iniciales

- El argumento header en pd.read_excel le dice a pandas que fila usará para obtener los nombres de las columnas. En el caso del excel de la captura, esa fila sería la 12. Si haces eso, `df.columns = df.iloc[0]` y saltar la primera fila se vuelve innecesario y dejarlo producirá comportamientos inesperados.
- Iterar sobre un dataframe en pandas debe ser tu ultimo recurso. Si lo estás haciendo, es posible que se pueda optimizar. Pandas tiene bucles internos hechos en C que son más rapidos que los bucles de Python.
- Si haces commit después de insertar cada registro, el proceso será lento. Yo lo suelo poner fuera del bucle.

##### Usando df.to_sql (requiere sqlalchemy)

Si tenés ganas de modificar tu código para que use [sqlalchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/), el código de ejemplo que te puedo ofrecer sería tan simple como:

```
colmap = {"excel_col1":"sql_col1", "excel_col2":"sql_col2", ...}

df.rename(columns=colmap).to_sql("tabla", cnx, if_exists="append", index=False)
```

`df.rename` crea una copia del dataframe anterior con las columnas renombradas, en este caso con las columnas de excel renombradas a su versión en sql para que to_sql genere la consulta.

to_sql recibe el nombre de la tabla, una conexión o motor de sqlalchemy y algunos argumentos extra. En este caso usamos `if_exists="append"` para que, si la tabla ya existe, agregue los datos, o de lo contrario sea creada. También usamos `index=False` para que no trate el indice (habitualmente el número de fila) como una columna más para la tabla.

##### Sin usar to_sql

De lo contrario, se me ocurrió un código util, que aunque más basico y lento, considero que podría ser más rapido que el código de tu pregunta.

```
colmap = {"excel_col1":"sql_col1", "excel_col2":"sql_col2", ...}
df = df.rename(columns=colmap)

cursor = cnx.cursor()

query = "INSERT INTO tabla(%s) VALUES (%s)" % (",".join(df.columns), ",".join(["%s"] * len(df.columns)))

cursor.executemany(query, df.itertuples(index=False))

cnx.commit()
```

Lo que hace esto es generar dinamicamente un insert usando los nombres de las columnas del dataframe y utilizar un método del cursor llamado executemany que aplica una consulta a cada elemento que genera un iterador. `df.itertuples()` devuelve un iterador que genera cada fila del dataframe en forma de [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), una subclase de tupla. index=False indica que no queremos que el indice forme parte de la namedtuple.